# I keep getting an error message in R while using twitteR

Tags: r, twitter, api

here is what I am doing:

```
tweets=searchTwitter("walmart",n=3000, lang="en",since="2021-01-08",until="2021-01-10")
```

And this is my error message:

```
Warning message:
In doRppAPICall("search/tweets", n, params = params, retryOnRateLimit = retryOnRateLimit,  :
  3000 tweets were requested but the API can only return 0
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

See [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39993266/9435355), it seems you can request tweets older than 7 days from the official Twitter API. See also the [documentation for the `searchTwitter` function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/twitteR/versions/1.1.9/topics/searchTwitter):

> Note that there are pagination restrictions as well as other limits on
> what can be searched, so it is always possible to not retrieve as many
> tweets as was requested with the n argument.

Try changing the `since` and `until` dates to something within the last 7 days to see if that does work.